# Export custom Google Maps view to vector Format

Tags: pdf, export, svg, google-maps

I have created a custom Google Map with markers and I'd like to export this map as a *Vector image*, including the copyright notices, for printing at a higher quality.

Is there a way to export a custom Google Map, including the markers, to SVG or PDF? All screenshots, even if exported as PDF, actually export as bitmaps.

Answer (score 1):

No, your browser never sees any of the vector stuff.

However, for your needs you should be able to print it with good quality anyway, just don't do it via a screenshot (well in theory it could work well too),

In your browser when on that page, use the print dialogue in the browser and print it to a PDF or directly to a printer. For example with Chrome's own print dialogue (notice the advanced settings too) you will get some pretty good settings and choices and it is using the the best underlying quality for printing directly, not doing it manually via a screenshot. Use 600dpi or 1200dpi, choose a big paper size if you would like that etc.

Take notice of the actual printed area and paper orientation (portrait/landscape).

So for short, no, no vectors, but good end result anyway?

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but that was (besides others) what I tried first and the quality really is not better then screenshotting the page (which even relieves me of the boundaries etc.). I was really hoping to somehow export the map, I do remember that there *used to be* an option (in the pre-Google+-times) to export the currently visible part to an SVG file.

Answer (score 0):

Many people forget, however, that these maps may not be used in the commercial sector in particular. If you use the map only for yourself, that should be ok. But there are many providers e.g. on Ebay and Etsy who sell maps in high resolution. This is not allowed with Google maps.

If you need vector maps in higher resolutions and styles for printing you can use the [Custom Vector Map Service](https://hebstreits.com/customizer) from Hebstreits. Here high-resolution vector maps are individually produced for private and commercial providers.

Disclaimer: I am author of Hebstreits Map Service and OpenStreetMap Contributor.